# Injecting dependencies into an MVVMLight ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, ninject, mvvm-light

I have a `ViewModelLocator` from MVVMLight containing my `MainViewModel`.

I have another singleton class `ResourceLogger` which does something else.

`ResourceLogger` is created in `App.xaml.cs` using:

```
var resourceLogger = kernel.Get<ResourceLogger>();
```

`MainViewModel` depends on `ResourceLogger`.

I am having problems injecting `ResourceLogger` into the `MainViewModel` as follows:

```
[Inject]
public MainViewModel(ResourceLogger resourceLogger) { ... }
```

The problem is that it creates two `ResourceLogger` classes.

The NinjectModule looks as follows:

```
Bind<ResourceLogger>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
Bind<MainViewModel>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

Is there some way to share the kernel between App.xaml.cs and ViewModelLocator?

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to have create public static class/variable for the kernel, then use it for all registration and calls to Get().

As an aside, you should do what you can to only have one call to kernel.Get() (or at least as few calls as possible) in your whole system.